# Technique to enable smooth page changing and prevent the browser redrawing for each page load

Tags: html, asp.net, caching, browser, web

I'll try explain the situation as best as possible..

I'm using ASP.NET with Bootstrap CSS. Every page uses the same master page. When I switch pages, the browser sometimes loads the new page without redrawing everything - only the HTML that has changed. Other times, it loads everything up again (so you see a white screen for a split second while the browser re-renders the HTML).

Is there a way I can configure the site to make the page transitions smoother? Has this got something to do with browser caching?

Comment: Maybe the browser IS reloading everythig, but it's so fast that you don't see it?

Comment: Possibly :) I am testing on localhost so you make a good point.

Comment: put the content in an `iframe` and on page change, make a *fade out/fade in* effect on the `iframe` element while it loads new content. The main page will stay unrefreshed.

Comment: You know, you could have your content inside an Ajax upload panel. That would ensure the master page elements don't reload. Lots of pros and cons, but that's stuff for too much of a lengthy discussion.

Comment: @Renan : I may be wrong, but I think in ASP.NET, there's always a full postback of the page, .NET dealing with updatepanels and viewstate to compute only the concerned updatepanel and leave the rest as is, but the whole HTML is sent as a response. I would need to test to be sure though...

Comment: @Bartdude I've been tinkering with update panels this weekend. I'm quite sure that while there may be a full postback there, the resulting HTML is parsed and the parts inside the panel are extracted. In the end only that block of html is replaced in the actual page you have on screen.

Comment: @Renan > I had a quick look online, and it seems you're right : http://encosia.com/why-you-should-not-place-your-whole-site-in-an-updatepanel/ , from the explanation there, it seems indeed that only a selected part of the HTML is in the response, and then treated by the pagerequestmanager. But still, I really hate writing server code  to perform client actions, it seems unintuitive to me, although you sometimes can't do it differently...

Comment: @Bartdude "I really hate writing server code to perform client actions, it seems unintuitive to me, although you sometimes can't do it differently" -> Story of my life. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

Well, although ASP.NET implements AJAX, and partial change of pages (through updatepanels for example) there's always a postback to the server with everything you do in .NET. Basically, there's always that "blank screen", but you probably don't see it in some cases, when the server answers quickly or you browser treats the HTML quicker for any reason.

The only possibility I know to avoid full postbacks is to get out of the .NET logic and do AJAX request yourself by writing client code only. But this possibly comes with other problems (like the controls you may add this way not being "known" by your server code, for example).

Comment: True, that. There's always a tradeoff. IMO the best way to go is to make your pages as light as you can. And I mean having as little visual content as possible while keeping it pleasant. Neat interfaces don't just make the loading faster and more responsive, they also make for pages your users will like better (or in the very least, dislike it less).